# Friend classes across different namespaces not working and namespace is not recognized

Tags: c++, oop, friend

I am having trouble with the use of friend class in C++
I am forward declaring the friend class and using the appropriate namespaces, so I don't know what  is going on.
Inside class  `MeshNamespace::Mesh` , `ReferenceElementNamespace::ReferenceElement` 's members are still unable to access private members of the former. Besides in  `ReferenceElement.hpp`, `MeshNamespace` identifier is not recognized.

If I forward-declare it as `class Mesh;` without the namespace it doesn't complain , but still doesn't work just as if there were no forward declaration at all;

//file  ReferenceElement.hpp

```
namespace ReferenceElementNamespace {
    class MeshNamespace::Mesh; // ReferenceElement.hpp:27:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MeshNamespace'
    class ReferenceElement : public IReferenceElement 
  {
  private:
  vector<Polygon> _referenceElementPolygons;   //(**)
  friend class MeshNameSpace::Mesh; //ReferenceElement.hpp:45:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MeshNameSpace'
  };
}
```

//file  Mesh.hpp

```
#include "Mesh.hpp"
    using namespace ReferenceElementNamespace;
    namespace MeshNamespace {
          class Mesh : public IMesh{
                  someFunction(ReferenceElement& referenceElement)
                  {
                    ReferenceElement ref;
                    Polygon &polygon = ref._referenceElementPolygons[0];  //Mesh.cpp:216:32: error: '_referenceElementPolygons' is a private member of 'ReferenceElementNamespace::ReferenceElement'
    ReferenceElement.hpp:34:23: note: declared private here   // in line (**)
                  }
         };
    }
```

Edit: By the way, I realized that forward-declaring  `class Mesh;` instead of `class MeshNamespace::Mesh;` gets accepted because it like declaring  a new class in namespace `ReferenceElementNamespace`, but then I am getting ambiguity in  another file where I use `MeshNamespace` and `ReferenceElementNamespace` with `using`. Still this doesn't solve anything

Comment: Have you tried to make the forward declaration in a namespace? E.g. `namespace MeshNamespace { class Mesh; }` I'm used to the fact that forward declaration of nested classes is not supported. You probably meant a class in a namespace instead but I'm not sure whether the compiler considers this as such as well.

Comment: Btw. you mixed `MeshNamespace` and `MeshNameSpace`.

Comment: With `namespace MeshNamespace { class Mesh; }`, I got it compiling: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/282b6e37316a9288)

Comment: @Scheff It worked! Thanks a lot. I added  `namespace MeshNamespace { class Mesh; }` right before `namespace ReferenceElementNamespace {` in `ReferenceElement.hpp` and that solved everything. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you want to write it

Comment: @Scheff what  did you mean with your second comment?

Comment: Pay attention to `Space`. Once you wrote it uppercase and once lowercase. That's another underhanded bug I had to fix. (Such typos can cost you a long time of code staring...) ;-)

Comment: Oh Thank you, yes I realized that in the IDE after my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I know:

1. Forward declarations in (other) namespaces are supported.
2. Forward declarations of nested classes are not supported.

OP wrote:

```
class MeshNamespace::Mesh;

class OtherClass {
friend class MeshNamespace::Mesh;
};
```

to forward declare a `class Mesh` in a `namespace MeshNamespace`.

It could be as well a `class MeshNamespace { class Mesh { } }` but this is a forward declaration of a nested class (which is not supported).

I'm not sure how to distinguish it, and it seems the compiler cannot as well. However, the fix is simple:

```
namespace MeshNamespace {
class Mesh;
}

class OtherClass {
friend class MeshNamespace::Mesh;
};
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c97b4602240adabf)

---

**Note:**

Since C++17, nested namespace definitions are allowed:
`namespace X::Y { }` is considered equal to `namespace X { namespace Y { } }`.

This seems to be true for class definitions as well. So, adding a definition

```
class MeshNamespace::Mesh { };
```

after the `namespace MeshNamespace` has been defined once is fine.
(However, this is an error as well before the `namespace MeshNamespace` has been defined at least once.)

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5999338e9068844)

Comment: By the way, as you see each of these classes inherits from an interface, which has only virtual functions, in case I had used only a virtual method, say `someFunction` and not a virtual class,  should I add the corresponding virtual method for the friend method in class `ReferenceElement` ? If not I am worried that when I create an object of `IMesh`,  I may not be able to use method `someFunction` , since it accesses private members of `IReferenceElement` were there is no virtual declaration of the friend method?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Not sure whether I got your other problem right... If I make a base class a friend to another class, and derived classes shall "inherit" this friendship - I just make a protected inline wrapper function, so that derived classes can call something they are allowed to.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6df251f79d3bb129) for the "inherited" friendship.

Comment: Mesh inherits from `IMesh`, `ReferenceElement` inherits from `IReferenceElement`. `Mesh::someFunction` is declared as friend in `ReferenceElement`.  If I make and object `IReferenceElement virtualObject` I am normally allowed to use it as if it were an object of `ReferenceElement.` If I want to do  `virtualObject.someFunction` this will access private members of` IMesh`, but `IMesh` has not declared `IReferenceElement` as a friend (only its derived class `Mesh` has declared the derived class `ReferenceElement` as a friend) so I am not sure this would work

Comment: @J.C.VegaO OK. I believe this is worth another question.

Comment: You are right I will try that later and come back if it doesn't work.